# GAP express word as product of conjugates of relators

Tags: group-theory, gap, computer-algebra-systems, finitely-generated

GAP can tell you if a word on a finite alphabet is expressible as a product of conjugates of a given list of words. In the example below, it tells us that the word $x^3yx^3y$ is expressible as a product of conjugates of the words $x^4$, $y^2$, $xyxy$:

```
gap> H := FreeGroup("x", "y");
<free group on the generators [ x, y ]>
gap> x := H.1;
x
gap> y := H.2;
y
gap> G := H / [ y^2, x^4, x*y*x*y ];
<fp group on the generators [ x, y ]>
gap> x := G.1;
x
gap> y := G.2;
y
gap> x^3*y*x^3*y = x^0;
true
```

However, telling us that such a product exists does not tell us what it is. For instance, in the example above, we have:

$x^3yx^3y = (x^3 \color{red}{y^2} x^{-3}) \cdot \color{red}{x^4} \cdot (y(\color{red}{xyxy})^{-1}y^{-1}) \cdot (y\color{red}{x^4}y^{-1})  \cdot \color{red}{y^2}$

Is there any way we can ask GAP (or any other computer algebra package) to actually compute such a product rather than merely telling us that it exists?

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but this is a very difficult problem in general. It if known that finitely presented groups exist in which the problem of deciding whether a word represents the identity is much more easier (in terms of complexity) that expressing the element as a product of conjugates of defining relators.

Comment: @DerekHolt From your comment I presume that when you ask Gap if an element in a presented group is trivial, it does not simply search through products of conjugates of relators.  Do you know what it does do?  If its "workings" can be printed to file, then the OP could write their own code to convert this to the form they require.

Comment: I think Alexander Hulpke could answer your question more accurately than I can. GAP typically has a number of possible methods for solving a problem and will attempt to select the best one, but then try another method if that fails. The example in your question is a small finite group, and I would guess that GAP uses coset enumeration in that case to obtain what is essentially the Cayley graph of the group. Of course this will not work for infinite groups, and methods based on rewriting can be attempted in that case.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the quotient group $G$ is small (the reason for small is related to Derek Holt's observatiuon that this is a hard problem), you could form suitable generators of the kernel (as conjugates of relators) and use the general rewriting mechanism to express elements (that is their `UnderlyingElement` in the free group) as word in the conjugate relators. In your example:

```
gap> rels:=Union(List(RelatorsOfFpGroup(G),r->List(Elements(G),
> e->r^UnderlyingElement(e))));
[ y^2, x^-1*y^2*x, x^4, (x*y)^2, (y*x)^2, x^-2*y^2*x^2, x^-1*(y*x)^2*x,
  y^-1*x^-1*y^2*x*y, y^-1*x^4*y, y^-1*(x*y)^2*y, x^-3*y^2*x^3,
  x^-2*(y*x)^2*x^2, y^-1*x^-2*y^2*x^2*y, y^-1*x^-1*(y*x)^2*x*y,
  y^-1*x^-3*y^2*x^3*y, y^-1*x^-2*(y*x)^2*x^2*y ]
gap> sub:=Subgroup(H,rels);
Group(<16 generators>)
gap> Index(H,sub);
8
gap> iso:=IsomorphismFpGroupByGenerators(sub,rels);
[ y^2, x^-1*y^2*x, x^4, (x*y)^2, (y*x)^2, x^-2*y^2*x^2, x^-1*(y*x)^2*x,
  y^-1*x^-1*y^2*x*y, y^-1*x^4*y, y^-1*(x*y)^2*y, x^-3*y^2*x^3,
  x^-2*(y*x)^2*x^2, y^-1*x^-2*y^2*x^2*y, y^-1*x^-1*(y*x)^2*x*y,
  y^-1*x^-3*y^2*x^3*y, y^-1*x^-2*(y*x)^2*x^2*y ] ->
[ F1, F2, F3, F4, F5, F6, F7, F8, F9, F10, F11, F12, F13, F14, F15, F16 ]
gap> elm:=x^3*y*x^3*y;;
gap> IsOne(elm);
true
gap> ImagesRepresentative(iso,UnderlyingElement(elm));
F3*F2*F5^-1*F1*F9
```

so the expression is $(x^4)\cdot (y^2)^x /(xyxy)\cdot (y^2)\cdot (x^4)^y$, by looking at the `rels` of indices 3,2,5,1,9.

Comment: From my understanding of your code, you obtain rels by taking each relator and conjugating by one preimage of each element of G.  Then you ask if elm is in the subgroup generated by rels.  However this will not in general be the normal closure of the relators.  Consider the presentation of the trivial group <a, b| a^2, b^3, ab>.  As G is trivial in this case rels is just the relators, which do not generate the whole group (ab does not generate C_2 * C_3).

Comment: If G is finite you do get a finite set of generators for the normal closure of the relators by first forming a set C of one preimage for each element of G, then taking cgd^-1 for each c in C, generator g and d in C representing the same element of G as cg.  Was this what you were thinking of, or did I misunderstand your code?